# Use instagram api through curl in php

Tags: php, curl, instagram-graph-api

I'm trying to use an instagram api in a php script...

The api url is "https://graph.instagram.com/*<'user-id>*?*<'params+token>*" and the curl to call is

`curl -X GET 'https://graph.instagram.com/<user-id>?<params+token>'`

which work if I call that with the terminal.

I've tried to convert it in php cURL:

```
$ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://graph.instagram.com/<user-id>?<params+token>');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    echo "!!!!!! " . $result;
```

$result is

```
{"error":{"message":"Invalid OAuth access token.","type":"OAuthException","code":190,"fbtrace_id":"***********"}}
```

what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have reason to believe your access token should work? "Invalid access token" seems... clear.

Comment: i've tried it manually and tested on the token debugger inside the "facebook for developer" site: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken

Comment: I don't think those tokens are valid for the older graph.instagram.com. Those tokens are only usable in the new one at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/user/ that hits graph.facebook.com.

Comment: do you know how to "translate" the cUrl -X GET "url" in a php script valid for graph.facebook.com?

Comment: I'd use the Facebook SDK for PHP.

Comment: How are you getting the token? Are you authenticating against the new Basic Display API?